# Issue with String as parameter

Tags: java, string, parameters, getter-setter, pojo

First of, sorry for my bad English.
I'm pretty new to java and we are learning it in School at the moment. In my Program I want to use String as a parameter but when I try to build an object I can't type anything in for the Parameter. Here's my bytecode:

```
public String gender;
public Waage(String pGender)
{
    gender = pGender;
}
```

As you can see I want the user to type in their gender, the variable gender will then be set to be the same as the parameter pGender. If I want to create an object with Bluej now, I just get the error that it cannot find symbol - variable x (for example female). Could someone please explain to me what I'm doing wrong or how to fix it? Thank you!
Also this is my first question here so if I did any big mistakes just tell me.

Edit:
My full code:

```
public class Waage
{ 
   public String gender;

   public Waage(String pGender)
   {
       gender = pGender;
   }

   public void changeGender(String pGender)
   {
       gender = pGender;
   }

   public String giveGender()
   {
       return gender;
   }
}
```

And the Error Message is If I would type in female :
Error: cannot find symbol - variable female

Comment: Please post your real code, post your full error message. You're talking about can't find symbol for variable x (or variable female???) but don't show the offending variable. You don't show the actual error message but rather paraphrase it and leave out some key information that it contains.

Comment: @pRaNaY It seems to be a constructor. The OP just hasn't posted enough code.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEals there you go sorry..

Comment: as per code of getter/setter(POJO) don't need to be a `Waage` constructor

Comment: And its a constructor

Comment: What do you mean by `"If I would type in female : Error: cannot find symbol - variable female"` -- type in female where? If you're typing in the console via a driver program, this error shouldn't happen. I suspect that you want to use an enum, something like `public enum Sex {MALE, FEMALE}`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels when I create a new Object in Bluej I have to type in something for the parameter pGender, there I want to type in male / female

Comment: @janmeymaster: this is key information -- please show the code causing the error. You've still yet to do this.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I'm Sorry but what do you mean by that?

Comment: Show the code where you try to create a new object in Bluej.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Nevermind I've fixed it. Still thank you for your time and help!

Comment: Please explain what you did for our benefit.

Comment: *"Show the code where you try to create a new object in Bluej."* There is no code for that. In BlueJ you click on a class and select something like "create instance" and the IDE asks you to provide the arguments for the existing constructor. It's not like OP wrote that dialog himself/herself :).

Comment: And just in case OP won't tell us how he/she fixed it: in this mentioned dialog (see my other comment above) you need to provide a String for gender. Here you need to wrap that String in quotes (e.g. `"female"`), otherwise (e.g. `female`) it would look for an existing variable with that name.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor,

```
public Waage(pGender)
{
    gender = pGender;
}
```

pGender is local variable of the constructor, that is taking String argument, and it is missing datatype. Edit that as below and it'll compile.

```
 public Waage(String pGender)
 {
     gender = pGender;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the cause is not passing string in double quotes in constructor call.

You must be creating your class's object like this:

```
Waage waage = new Waage(female);
```

Either use :

```
Waage waage = new Waage("female");
```

or:

```
String gender = "female";
Waage waage = new Waage(gender);
```

Comment: answers aren't supposed to be used as comments